# Filter for various scala types

Tags: scala, types, filter

I am trying to get a function that will take a 'type' as a parameter and then return all occurrences of that type.

```
val a = List(1 , 2 , true, "Hello")

def f(a: List[Any], b: ???): List[Any] = {
  a.filter(p => p.isInstanceOf[b])
}

f(a,???)
```

So that `f(a,Int)` would return `List(1, 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider `ClassTag` as follows,

```
def f[T: scala.reflect.ClassTag](xs: List[Any]) = xs.collect { case v: T => v  }
```

Hence

```
f[Int](xs)
res: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Note `ClassTag` is of interest in collections whose elements type(s) are unknown at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: Using deprecated `Manifest`. See accepted answer for way forward.

Try:

```
def f [T:Manifest](a: List[Any]): List[T] = a.collect {case x: T => x}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
val filteredList = f[Int](a)
```

Keep in mind, a `List[Any]` is almost always a bad idea. There's probably a better way to solve the problem, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: `Manifest` is obsolete, you should use type tags instead. See: [TypeTags and Manifests](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html). Agree that it's usually not a good idea to have a `List[Any]`.

Comment: `ClassTag` works when pattern-matching on `T`, I don't think `TypeTag` does.